# How to use nodejs or gulp to execute a series of shell commands?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am working in the development on my mac laptop. Here are what I need to do to start the development environment:

1) open console, 'sudo mongod' - start mongoDB server

2) open another console, 'mongo' - open mongo console for debug CRUD process

3) open another console, 'cd /projects/myProject', 'npm start' - start the nodejs api service on localhost

4) open another console, and 'cd /projects/myProject', 'gulp' - start the gulp browserify & watch process

5) open another console, 'cd /projects/myProject/build', 'httpster' - start a mini http server for front-end built code, so that I can access it in browser at 0.0.0.0: 3333

If you do those everyday, it is not fun at all. I think it is a common problem which is very likely to have a solution. 
Is there anyway to complete all above by executing one single js file? e.g.: node start.js.
If would be best if you can provide some demo code.

Thank you!

- Nick

Comment: Not sure it should be gulp responsibility to do what you are describing. Why not to write a little shell script to automate all those steps?

Comment: I am also open to shell script, but I am not very familiar with shell script. That's the reason I can't choose the best solution for this. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [gulp-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell). I use it to start mongoDB from gulp.

[image]